# Can we believe the Google Pagespeed insight results?

Tags: magento2.2.6, pagespeed

I have checked the speed of our Magento site on Google pagespeed insight and see that its showing inconsistent pagespeed scores.

For better understanding, please see the below images

[image: This test has done at 2.24 PM]

[image: This test has done at 2.25 PM]

I have read about this inconsistency of results but not got a satisfied results. Could anyone please help me to understand about this?

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: the problem that measurement is wrong, because you have `http` and we dont see your issues list... and why for gods sake you have version 2.2.6???? 2.3.3 is the latest...

Answer (score 0):

The results depend on load time, which not constant (TTFB, network, DNS, etc). Additionally, page speed uses different servers (locations).

But on average, page score is almost the same (24 hours, check every 10 minutes):

[image]